# Reference for measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

I will start studying "**measure theory**" in a self-taught way.

I would like to know if you could recommend some books?

I was thinking of starting to study with: "Kesavan, S. (2019). Measure and integration. (First Edition).
Singapore "

My study methodology is a theoretical book + a book with many problems to solve.

Thanks so much!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11591/suggestions-for-a-good-measure-theory-book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are going to study on your own, it is better to look at several books and find the one that seems more understandable to yourself. Based on this, I propose several books - they are all searched in net and can be downloaded

1. Donald L. Cohn (auth.) - Measure Theory
2. Halmos P.R. - Measure Theory
3. J. L. Doob (auth.) - Measure Theory
4. Elias M. Stein, Rami Shakarchi - Real analysis_ measure theory, integration, and Hilbert spaces
5. Richard L. Wheeden, Antoni Zygmund - Measure and Integral_ An Introduction to Real Analysis
6. Sheldon Axler - Measure, Integration & Real Analysis
7. D.H. Fremlin - Measure theory (5 volumes)
8. Makarov_-_Lektsii_Po_Veschestvennomu_Analizu (Ru)
9. J Yeh - Real Analysis _ Theory of Measure and Integration

Comment: Maybe also Oxtoby, Measure and category and Billingsey, Probability and measure.

Comment: The electronic version of my book Measure, Integration & Real Analysis is legally available for free at http://measure.axler.net/. This book has been published in Springer's Gradate Texts in Mathematics series as an Open Access book.

Comment: @Sheldon Axler. Thanks. It's very nice from you to have it on free download. Added it to my library. I'll look it, but meanwhile let me say, that I am very jealous of that you knew Paul Halmos. I began to study the theory of measure from his book and still consider it one of the best.